# Storing Indices of a Generated Random Matrix in a Seperate Matrix

Tags: matlab, random

I am generating a random graph G of 9 * 9 matrix:

```
G = round(rand(9));
G = triu(G) + triu(G,1)';
G = G - diag(diag(G))
```

And I am extracting randomly some rows and columns from above matrix:

```
k = randperm(9);
mnew = G(k(1:4),k(2:6));
```

mnew =

```
0     1     0     0     1
0     1     0     1     0
1     0     1     1     1
0     1     0     0     1
```

Now, I want to create a matrix storing the indices of rows and columns which got extracted in mnew

Comment: `[r,c]=find(mnew);`  `indMat = [r,c]`  Is this what you want? If not, what output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `mnew` you have extracted the elements of the matrix `G` that are in the 
rows given by `k(1:4)` and in the columns `k(2:6)` therefore, if I've understood your question, you have to generate the possible couple given by  `k(1:4)` and `k(2:6)`.

Defined:

```
k_r=k(1:4)
k_c=k(2:6)
```

You can generate the couples (*row*, *column*) this way:

```
row_idx=reshape(repmat(k_r,length(k_c),1),20,1)
col_idx=reshape(repmat(k_c,length(k_r),1)',20,1)
idx=[row_idx col_idx]
```

or, simply looping through the `k_r` and `k_c` values generating the 
different couples:

```
idx=[];
for i=1:length(k_r)
   for j=1:length(k_c)
      idx=[idx;k_r(i) k_c(j)];
   end
end
```

If, for example:

```
k_r=[1 8 9 7]
```

and

```
k_c=[8 9 7 6 5]
```

you get:

```
idx=[1     8
     1     9
     1     7
     1     6
     1     5
     8     8
     8     9
     8     7
     8     6
     8     5
     9     8
     9     9
     9     7
     9     6
     9     5
     7     8
     7     9
     7     7
     7     6
     7     5];
```

Where the first column hold the row indexes and the second the column indexes.

You can `reshape` the resulting index matrix in order to better represent the
results:

```
reshape_idx=reshape(idx',2,5,4)
```

this generate the following `(2x5x4)` matrix where each (:,:,i) block represents the row index (first row) and column index (second row)_ of each row of `mnew`:

```
reshape_idx(:,:,1) =
     1     1     1     1     1
     8     9     7     6     5

reshape_idx(:,:,2) =
     8     8     8     8     8
     8     9     7     6     5

reshape_idx(:,:,3) =
     9     9     9     9     9
     8     9     7     6     5

reshape_idx(:,:,4) =
     7     7     7     7     7
     8     9     7     6     5
```

Hope this helps,

Qapla'